# How do I auto resize the font used in labels of the UI form in qt, according to resolution?

Tags: qt, qt5, qfont

I am currently developing  an application. And my development computer resolution is 1366*768, I know how to make the application size auto resizable according to resolution. But the problem is in the labels used in application. If the resolution of the monitor  is less than 1366*768, the labels becomes cramped and unable to see text, if i keep the font low, and if i use higher resolution monitor the text in those labels looks very tiny. I know one solution that is to check the resolution of monitor during the application start and assign appropriate font to the labels dynamically. But this method takes more time as i have to first create a list of resolution with appropriate font by using trial and error method. And this also requires lot of code. I was wondering if there is any feature or function in qt that i am unaware of to auto scale the font as per resolution. Thanks!

Comment: Use point instead of pixel for font size?

Comment: @AndreySemenov please can you tell me whats the use/advantage of using point? I normally assign the font size in the ui designer itself

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference

Comment: @AndreySemenov In Qtcreator designer the font size is expressed in point itself.